# String constant for a new line + tab?

Tags: c#, string

I want a C# 4 string constant to represent a new line and a tab as in the following:

```
internal const string segment = "\r\n\t";
```

I know there is Environment.Newline which I guess I could use like this:

```
internal const string segment = Environment.NewLine + "\t";
```

My question is what is the most efficient way to construct a string constant that has a new line and a tab?

Comment: The second one is better as it's platform independent

Comment: Efficient in whay way?  Readability? Pure speed? OS portability?  "\r\n\t" will probably give you marginally better performance but may not be suitable for all environments including browsers, Windows/Unix, etc.)

Comment: @orn: On the contrary, the value of the second *absolutely depends* on the platform.

Comment: @JonSkeet but, because the value of the expression depends on the platform, the correctness of the code does not.  I would also note that since Environment.NewLine is a property, it cannot be used in a constant expression, so the second declaration of segment needs to change in order to compile successfully (as noted in Reed Copsey's answer)

Comment: @phoog Jon is correct, here, though - the second is a functionally different option than the first.  I *suspect* the goal is to use Environment.NewLine, but there are specific cases (such as trying to match an existing protocol) where `\r\n` may be the proper choice for any executing platform.  There is no way to know which option is *correct* on a given platform without more information.

Comment: @ReedCopsey agreed.  I was just trying to point out that the term "platform independent" can be confusing: We create platform-independent things (e.g., .NET assembly) by using platform-dependent elements (e.g., CLR jit compiler).

Comment: yes @JonSkeet therefor the code would be platform independent

Comment: @orn: The value of the string depends on the platform. It may well be that the platform-specific string value is the desired behaviour, but I would call any value which changes based on what platform you're using, a platform-specific (not platform independent) piece of code.

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought we were discussing the question and the code not just the NewLine value.  Yes the NewLine value is indeed platform specific.  That was the whole point.

Comment: @orn: Well, you claimed the second line of code was platform independent. I think it would be *much* clearer to say it's a portable way of creating a string representing the platform-specific line separator followed by a tab.

Comment: Does 2 even compile? I get, "the expression being assigned to segment must be constant."

Doh! Read further into the thread.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Provided you declare the string as `const`, as above, there is absolutely no difference in terms of efficiency.  Any constant will be substituted at compile time and use an interned string.

Unfortunately, the second option is not a compile time constant, and will not compile.  In order to use it, you'd need to declare it as:

```
internal static readonly string segment = Environment.NewLine + "\t";
```

I, personally, find this very clear in terms of intent, and it would be my preference, even though it's not going to be a compile time constant.  The extra overhead/loss of efficiency is so incredibly minor that I would personally choose the clear intent and legible code over the compile time constant.

Note that using `Environment.NewLine` also has the benefit of being *correct* if you port this code to Mono, and your goal is to use the current platforms line separator.  The first will be incorrect on non-Windows platforms in that specific case.  If your goal is to specifically include `"\r\n\t"`, and do not desire the platform-specific line separator, then `Environment.NewLine` would be an inappropriate choice.

Comment: "Correct" depends on how the OP is planning to use it. If the aim is to represent "carriage return, linefeed, tab" then the first form is correct and the second is not. If the aim is to represent "the line separator for the current platform followed by a tab" then the second form is correct. Neither is universally the right thing to do.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, I was assuming that the desire on the OP's part to use Environment.NewLine suggested that the OP wanted a line separator.

Comment: @JonSkeet Esp. since the OP stated the intent was to create a "constant to represent a new line and a tab".

Comment: @ReedCopsey: I'm always cautious in this matter, as a lot of people use Environment.NewLine assuming it's *always* the right thing to do, even when they're actually talking network protocols which have a specific line separator.

Comment: @JonSkeet Good point... Edited my answer to include that as a detail.

Answer (score 5):

`const` won't work. use `static readonly`.

```
internal static readonly string segment = Environment.NewLine + "\t";
```

Comment: Constants need to be Constant Strings "This is a Const"

Comment: @DJKRAZE  - can you elaborate? This is an acceptable way to create a constant value.

Comment: internal static string segment = Environment.NewLine + "\t"; will work or make it a private static string.

Comment: then i could override the value later on. `readonly` prevents that.

Comment: @DJKRAZE Non-constant strings need to be non-constant. `Environment.NewLine` isn't constant and so can't be used in creating a `const`.

Comment: duh.. If you read what I wrote about either making it a private or a static you will see that I answered the question.. Dupa Skulvison

Comment: @Daniel what I was saying Environment.NewLine is not a const constants expect " " is all I was trying to pointout so the down voting is truly unnecessary..

Answer (score 1):

Pure speed efficiency then the first will win, especially since the second can't be made `const` and then can't be compiled in.

Still, the second is going to be very darn fast indeed, so I wouldn't care.

Much more important is that these are just plain not the same thing.

It comes down to "why are you using \r\n\t"?

If you're using \r\n\t because you're on Windows and on Windows newlines are normally \r\n, then you should definitely use:

```
internal static readonly string segment = Environment.NewLine + "\t";
```

Using the other would be wrong, and could introduce bugs you won't see for years to come.

If you're using \r\n because you're working with a specification that says "separate segments with a CRLF followed by a tab", then you should definitely use:

```
internal const string segment = "\r\n\t";
```

Using the other would be wrong.

This is something that does bite people for real. Windows people write HTTP code that just happens to use a Windows newline between headers two between the headers and body. Then it gets ported to somewhere where the newline is \n and it breaks because HTTP mandates \r\n no matter what the system used. The same applies the other way around.

(Under the strict/permissive principle, it can also be a good idea to assume that other code out there will keep getting this wrong, and accept all the various newline forms out there).